# Get key, value pair from Django object in template

Tags: django

How do I get key,value pair from object from get_object_or_404 in template, passed from view to template as context?

```
#views.py
def detail(request):
    unknown = get_object_or_404(UnknownModel)
    return render(request, 'app/display.html', { 'some_data':unknown })
```

and in app/display.html, I've been trying various approaches:

```
{{ some_data }}
{{ some_data.keys }}
{{ some_data.items }}

{% for key, value in some_data.items %}
{{ key }} - {{ value }}
{% endfor %}}
```

but none work.
If I knew the fields, I can access easily as below, but that's not the case

```
{{ some_data.field_1 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `unknown` is instance of `UnknownModel` model.
In template, you are trying to iterate over this instance fields, but `items` method works
for dictionaries, not for your model. You can provide `items` method in your model to return dictionary with fields that you want or use following snippet:

```
{% for key, value in some_data.__dict__.items %}
{{ key }} - {{ value }}
{% endfor %}}
```

Method above will display many internal data related to your instance. Another (better) way of doing this is to convert your model instance to the dictionary inthe view and then pass it to the template. To achieve that, you can use `django.forms.models.model_to_dict` method.

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def detail(request):
    unknown = get_object_or_404(UnknownModel)
    return render(request, 'app/display.html', {'some_data':model_to_dict(unknown)})
```

Comment: will these be ordered dict ? in my test, the output follows Model fields in order , but is this guaranteed?